# Read XML with ab:tag format using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to xml, c#. I am following this tutorial: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564

But my xml file is little different. The xml that I want to read in my c# code is this: http://api.nextag.com/buyer/synd.jsp?search=ipod&ver=15&token=AQB7dB$kB8ULvbGT&pid=1807

Code I am trying to read this xml is:

---

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

XElement xelement = XElement.Load("http://api.nextag.com/buyer/synd.jsp?search=ipod&ver=15&token=AQB7dB$kB8ULvbGT&pid=1807");
XNamespace nxtg = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-01-11T08:31:30";

IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
// Read the entire XML
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
//Console.WriteLine(employee);
//Console.WriteLine(employee.Value);

if (employee.Element(nxtg + "search-category") == null)
continue;
else
Console.WriteLine(employee.Element(nxtg + "search-category").Value);
//Console.WriteLine(employee.Element("EmpId").Value);
}
```

---

But no luck. Anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xelement.Elements()` will return direct children of root element. In your case that will be elements `nxtg:publisher`, `nxtg:search-query`, `nxtg:search-category` etc. Thus `nxtg:search-category` is a direct child of root element, it also will selected as `employee`. That's why you can't find it in children of `employee`. You should do following instead:

```
// keep in mind, you have incorrect namespace value
XNamespace nxtg = "http://namespace.nextag.com/business-objects";
var searchCategory = xelement.Element(nxtg + "search-category");
var node = searchCategory.Element(nxtg + "node");
var displayName = (string)node.Element(nxtg + "display-name");
var value = (int)node.Element(nxtg + "value");
```